# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

This is my first post on stackoverflow! But i'm a master student at UIO so I'm not after getting a lot of help(if you even choose to) but perhaps a pointer towards where I could look to understand the problem better! And If you don't like my way of showing the problems then please do comment on that, and it will be better next time!

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1175)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1251)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateStudentDao.getAllStudents(HibernateStudentDao.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getAllStudents(Unknown Source)
no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.getAllStudents(DefaultStudentSystem.java:168)
no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.gui.controller.ApiController.jsonAddLocation(ApiController.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_BA ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(LATITUDE)"; SQL statement:
update student set name=?, latitude=?, longitude=? where student_id=? [23001-136]
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1098)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180)
  org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1175)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1251)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
 no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateStudentDao.getAllStudents(HibernateStudentDao.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getAllStudents(Unknown Source)
no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.getAllStudents(DefaultStudentSystem.java:168)
no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.gui.controller.ApiController.jsonAddLocation(ApiController.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

From the stacktrace :

> no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateStudentDao.getAllStudents(HibernateStudentDao.java:54)

the code:

```
public Collection<Student> getAllStudents() {    
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();    
    String hql = "from Student";    
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);    
    return (Collection<Student>)query.list();    <- java:54
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint violation exception usually happens when you are trying to insert data into the table row with a value that violates any set constraints in it.

Please make sure the value inserted into the column is not violating the constraint set
e.g if column is having unique index then make sure the value is unique with other records.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is triggering a flush, which leads to your ConstraintViolationException. Unfortunately you were not given this error at save time, but your error is certainly not related to this query.

Investigate your inserts prior to this query. Try flushing at the same time you save (.saveAndFlush() / .save(flush:true)) to try identify your bad inserts immediately, Hopefully Hibernate and JDBC will give you a proper error message telling you exactly what you did wrong instead of this unspecific constraint violation.

Comment: My goal was to be able to change latitude and longitude, but I simply couldn't with my constraints.
<property name="longitude" not-null="true" unique = "true"/>
<property name="latitude" not-null="true" unique = "true"/>

Then changing these values to:

<property name="latitude"/>
<property name="longitude"/>

Fixed the issue, I guess rookie mistake! But thanks a bunch :)

Comment: This is a prime example of one of the reasons many don't like Hibernate. If you don't understand how Hibernate thinks, your errors appear in non-obvious places and can waste hours and hours searching for your bug in the wrong place.